# Warning about partition offset when installing Debian

Tags: linux, debian, system-installation, debian-installer

I got an error:

> the partition `/dev/sda1` assigned to `/` starts at an offset of 3584 bytes from the minimum alignment for this disk, which may lead to very poor performance.

I want to install Debian on my 500 GB portable hard drive.
I allocated 40 GB to `/`, and the rest is for `/home`.

Comment: Looks like you have a disk with a 4kB physical sector size, and the partition start address is not aligned to a multiple of 4096. 3584 is exactly 512 bytes short of 4096. This can indeed lead to performance problems. For more information, see [Advanced Format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Format)

Comment: @JohanMyréen How to solve it?

Comment: You will need to repartition the disk and choose a starting offset for the partition that is a multiple of 4096 bytes.

Comment: Recreate the partition table

Comment: After repartition, It works well.